# JavaScript check if one object property value is exist on another object property

Tags: javascript

I have this array of Object:

```
let mapping =  [ { "value": "title", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "short_message", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "aff_code", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "other_data", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "created_at", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_active", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "brand", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "old_price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "subcategory", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "category", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "widget_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "image_urls", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "description", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null } ];
```

and another object is :

```
let newField = [ { "new_field_name": "one ", "new_field_value": "" }, { "new_field_name": "url", "new_field_value": "" } ];
```

Now, I want to check if the object property **new_field_name** value from `newField` is exist on **value** property from `mapping`

Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: new_field_name has two objects, each with a new_field_name property. Which one should we use?

Comment: @OriolVilaseca its should be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```js
let mapping =  [ { "value": "title", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "short_message", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "aff_code", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "other_data", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "created_at", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_active", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "brand", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "old_price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "subcategory", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "category", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "widget_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "image_urls", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "description", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null } ]; 

let newField = [ { "new_field_name": "one ", "new_field_value": "" }, { "new_field_name": "url", "new_field_value": "" } ];

for(let field of newField) {
    let find = mapping.filter(m => m.value == field.new_field_name);
    if(find.length > 0) console.log(`${field.new_field_name} exists`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `indexOf()` in order to check if the value in the one object exists in another object. So in this case it would be something like:

```
let doesExist;
for(let single in new_field_name){
    for(let single1 in mapping){
        if(single1.value.(indexOf(single.new_field_name) > -1){
            doesExist = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to check if your wanted value exists in another object's property value.

```
for(const field of newField){
if(mapping.some((data) => data.value === field.new_field_name)) 
   field.new_field_value = 'true';
}

console.log(newField);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mapping =  [ { "value": "title", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "short_message", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "aff_code", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "other_data", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "created_at", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_active", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "brand", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "old_price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "subcategory", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "category", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "widget_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "image_urls", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "description", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null } ]; 

let newField = [ { "new_field_name": "one ", "new_field_value": "" }, { "new_field_name": "url", "new_field_value": "" } ];


for (nf of newField) {
    for (m of mapping) {
        console.log(m.value == nf.new_field_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the foundational nested `for-loop`, which must be understood first.

```
let mapping =  [ { "value": "title", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "short_message", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "aff_code", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_url", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "other_data", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_id", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "created_at", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "product_active", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "brand", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "old_price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "subcategory", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "category", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "price", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "widget_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "campaign_name", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "image_urls", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null }, { "value": "description", "text": "Do Not Import", "custom": null } ]; 
let newField = [ { "new_field_name": "one ", "new_field_value": "" }, { "new_field_name": "url", "new_field_value": "" } ];

for (let testerIndex = 0; testerIndex < newfield.length; testerIndex++) {
    testerVal = newfield[testerIndex].new_field_name;
    //console.log(`testerVal: ${testerVal}`);

    for (let testedIndex = 0; testedIndex < mapping.length; testedIndex++) {
        testedVal = mapping[testedIndex].value;
        //console.log(`testedVal: ${testedVal}`);

        if (testerVal === testedVal){
            console.log(`Value "${testerVal}" exists in a mapping object`);
        }
    }// end inner for loop    
}// end outer for loop
```